# "...along with which comes the inner voice..." vs "...along with which the inner voice comes ..."

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

> “Seek out that particular mental attribute which makes you feel most deeply and vitally alive,
>
> `along with which comes the inner voice` `which` says, 'This is the real me,'
>
> and when you have found that attitude, follow it.”

**This is a quote from William James**.

I do not understant what the subject for verb `comes` is ?

It seems to me that a bit of meaning is about

either `the inner voice comes along with that particular mental attitude`

or `that particular mental attitude comes along with the inner voice`

I am not sure which one is correct.

I know some usages of English put a verb before it's subject such as poems.

Also does the second `which` refer to `the inner voice`?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The inner voice* is the subject, *which* (= *that particular mental attribute*) is the complement, of *comes with*.

So the meaning is

> The inner voice comes with that particular mental attribute ...

The inversion is grammatical (and common in a literary style) when certain things come first in the clause; for example:

- some negative polarity adverbials (inversion is compulsory):

> **Never** *had I* seen that before.
>
> **Scarcely** *had they left*, than I remembered it.

- a quotation:

> **"That was close!"** *said Jane*.

The construction *(preposition) which* does not invert normally:

> The axe **with which** *he felled* the tree

but in a literary style, especially with verbs like *come* and *go* (used metaphorically) and *be*, it is quite normal (examples out of the iWeb corpus):

> Most Ghanaian main dishes are organized around a starchy staple food, **with which** *goes a sauce* or soup containing a Protein source.
>
> ... an inner room, **from which** *comes a piercing shriek* ...
>
> Groups are also be given small cards **on which** *are written the key measures* of the New Deal